# Split TIFF and shapefile into smaller parts

Tags: qgis, gdal, shapefile, geotiff-tiff

I have a large TIFF file (14 GB), and along with it, I have a shapefile, covering parts of the TIFF in different shapes

I want to basically just split the TIFF into smaller squares, while also generating a new shapefile if there is a/any shape(s) for that square, so in the end I want to have x-number of TIFF images and x-number of shapefiles with n-number of shapes inside the shape.
If it's possible to also skip all the TIFFs without any shape, that would be great.

Is this possible?

Comment: Clip raster by mask layer

Comment: No, that would give me a tif image for every shape, and that won't help me.
I want to have a sqaure be, say 10km and if that square happens to cover 4 shape files, i want one tif and a shape-file with the info for those four shape files

Comment: Or am i perhaps mistaken here?

Comment: A lot of things are possible in QGIS. You need to break down your workflow into single steps which correspond to a tool in QGIS, and as BERA already teasered, `clip raster by mask layer` is one of those steps. Another would be merging the corresponding shapefiles.

Comment: Yeah sure, i was more asking if anyone had more specific details. Have already tried `clip raster by mask layer`, there's only one shapefile in the beginning so nothing should need merging.
Also tried splitting the shape into sqares, but not sure how to then cut the raster into the same squares, while also getting the shape info.
Hmm..

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. "Is it possible?" Questions aren't all that useful, since pretty much everything is possible with GIS. We use a Focused question/Best answer model, so Questions with "and" in the title are likely to violate the One question per Question policy emphasized by the Tour. So yes, it is certainly possible; all you need to do is start working the task. You'll need to decide if, having established a tile scheme, you want the image chunks to be fixed size, or grow to the limits of the shapes that overlap that tile. Then you can start scripting.

Comment: After some more thinking and playing around i think i managed to get around it. My question was a two in one because i thought you actually had to split the tif and shape in one command. Realized i can just create my grid and then split the tif and separately split the shape according to the grid and just map them together with their corresponding index in the order. Looks like it is/will work. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first project with geo data and for some reason I thought if I split the tif I must do the shape at the same time, so there should be a command to do just that.

My solution:

- Created a grid with the squares of my wanted size
- Split the tif
  according to the grid and looping through the grid doing one output
  for each
- Do the same for the shape with the Intersection feature

Then in my later steps I can just map them all together with the index in the name.